Find maximum negatives allowed

Given an array of positive numbers of size n, pick as many items as possible from this array and multiply by -1, such that the cumulative sum is always greater than 0. Return how many items can be made negative as result.
Example:
Test case1 : [5,3,1,2]
Result = 2
Explanation:
pick indices 1 and 2 and make them negative
so [5,-3,-1,2]
cumulative sum is [5,2,1,3]
There are other possibilities also like [5,-3,1,-2]

My coding approach is like this:
static int solve(int[] arr) {
    long sum = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for(int e : arr) {
        int neg = -e;
        if(sum + neg >0) {
            result++;
            sum += neg;
        } else {
            sum += e;
        }
    }
    return result;
} 

But my approach is not correct as it gives wrong output for some cases, for example:
arr = [5,2,3,5,2,3]

Expected output = 3, my code results = 2

possible solution is [5,-2,3,5,-2,-3]

What is the correct approach to solve this?

Does this problem have a web page? If so, it would be polite to include a link.

@OldDogProgrammer, I don't have a link for this problem

I've noticed that many of your questions are related to LeetCode and other challenge like problems.   Not to discourage you from posting on SO but did you know there is an exchange devoted to this type of programming.  It's called  Code Golf.  Thought you might like it.

@WJS Competitive programming and code golf are not the same. Very rarely do the solution techniques overlap. Efficiency is usually completely ignored for code golf challenges.

@Unmitigated Well, when I read some of the problems on Code Golf they sure resembled  many I have seen on the competitive programming sites.

@WJS I did not mean to imply otherwise, but code golf challenges are often solved by brute force as the rules there only require solutions to theoretically solve the problem eventually. Algorithms questions are better asked here.

Thanks for the reply. Since these problems do not have pages accessible to us, it might be helpful for future problems if you could share constraints and expectations.

You could always attempt to negate the current element if it is possible while keeping track of the elements removed so far in a multiset or priority queue. If the current element cannot be removed from the sum, try to replace it with the largest element previously removed if the latter is greater.
static int solve(int[] arr) {
    long sum = 0;
    int result = 0;
    var removed = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int x : arr) {
        if (sum - x > 0) {
            sum -= x;
            removed.add(x);
            ++result;
        } else if (!removed.isEmpty() && removed.peek() > x) {
            sum += removed.poll() - x;
            removed.add(x);
        } else sum += x;
    }
    return result;
}


Thank you, I am trying to understand this. sum += removed.lastKey() - x; here we are still reducing by x right, then removed.merge(x, -1, Integer::sum) why we are reducing its frequency in map, instead of incrementing it.

@learner That was a typo. I fixed the method.

Am I right in thinking this algorithm has O(N log N) time complexity? I was thinking about attempting a brute-force solution which would have been exponential.

@k314159 Yes, it is O(N log N).
